# Autofilter for multiple columns in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Can you please let check what is the error in below vba macro? Trying to autofilter two columns based on 
criteria. I am not able to filter field 8 and field 9 based on below code.

```
Worksheets("Demo_Sheet").Activate
With Worksheets("Demo_Sheet").Range("A1")
.AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="<=" & Format(Now() + 5, "m/d/yyyy"), Criteria2:=">=" & Format(Now() - 5, "m/d/yyyy"), Operator:=xlAnd
.AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:=">=.95"
End With
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
```

Comment: Did you try the macro recorder to see how the code would look like? And actually you **must not** format your dates. Instead filter for their value `cDbl(Now() + 5)` formatted filter on dates don't work, because `Format()` returns a string. And strings cannot work with `>` or `<`.

Answer (score 1):

this gave me an answer

```
Worksheets("Demo_Sheet").Activate
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="<=" & Format(Now() + 5, "m/d/yyyy"), Criteria2:=">=" & Format(Now() - 5, "m/d/yyyy"), Operator:=xlAnd
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:=">=.95"
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
```